# Do I need an article with a job title?

Tags: indefinite-articles, zero-article

which form is correct in the following paragraph?

1. ...his training as an industrial engineer...
2. ...his training as industrial engineer...

> The Scholarship in Petroleum’s program is certainly the best chance Dilia has to learn new techniques and technologies that are not available in our country to take advantage of one of the main sources of energy for human use. Using this source is necessary but it needs to be done carefully to avoid draining it all, which is the reason I think **his training as *an* industrial engineer** can be complemented with this Master's to form a researcher with the capability to find sustainable alternatives of use.

Comment: Potentially a duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/141143/191178

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Engineer** is a countable noun: all singular countable nouns must have an appropriate qualifying determiner* (a/an, the, my, John's, any, etc.)

*There are exceptions but these need not concern us here.

Comment: So none of the exceptions can be job titles?

Comment: @nnnnnn: There are. "It's nice to be President."

Comment: @Greybeard It could be exchanged "as an" by "of"?: ...his training of industrial engineer...

Comment: @pepo No, it can't.

Comment: @Greybeard I rewrite the whole paragraph, please let me know your thoughts: The Scholarship in Petroleum’s program is certainly the best chance Dilia has to learn new techniques and technologies that are not available in our country to take advantage of one of the main sources of energy for human use. Using this source is necessary but it needs to be done carefully to avoid draining it all, which is the reason I think he can complement his training as an industrial engineer with this master to attain the insights necessary to find sustainable alternatives of use.

Comment: @pepo My thoughts are that EL&U does not proofread. There are still serious errors.

Comment: @Greybeard What is the point in telling there are serious mistakes if you do not indicate them?. I am asking for help because I do not master the language yet. Therefore, I cannot see those serious mistakes..

Comment: *What is the point in telling there are serious mistakes if you do not indicate them?* **1** If your dog is ill, and you take it to a garage and ask them to cure it, you have done the wrong thing. **2** If EL&U corrected sentences and paragraphs for students, the site would be filled and professional proofreaders would be without a job. **3** Correction errors takes a lot of time. **4** A lot of your paragraph is incomprehensible and EL&U would have to ask you for many more details - the formal of EL&U makes this impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you left out the "a" in "2....his training as industrial engineer.." but either way, 1 is correct.

Try searching Google for "using a or an" next time.

Comment: I don't believe the question is actually asking about *a* or *an.* In any case, that's definitely trivial **and** a duplicate. I believe the alternatives were what is being asked about. Unfortunately your answer arrived during the edit.

Comment: @tomofv It could be exchanged "as an" by "of"?: ...his training of industrial engineer...